# ASP.NET MVC 3 jQuery fullCalendar

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, fullcalendar

I am trying to implement jquery full calendar with json event updates. I have no idea why oit's not working. Her is my layout.cstml head

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="../../Scripts/fullcalendar.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript">        </script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.3.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="../../Content/fullcalendar.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="../../Content/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"    />



 </head>
```

Here is my index.cshtml

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}


 <h2>@ViewBag.Message</h2>
 <p>
To learn more about ASP.NET MVC visit <a href="http://asp.net/mvc" title="ASP.NET    MVC     Website">http://asp.net/mvc</a>.
 </p>

   <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {
     $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            events: "/Home/CalendarData"
        });
    });  
   </script>

  <div id="calendar">
  </div>
```

And my controller

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Web;
 using System.Web.Mvc;
 using MvcApplication4.Models;

 namespace MvcApplication4.Controllers
  {
   public class HomeController : Controller
   {
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";

        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult About()
    {
        return View();
    }


    [HandleError]

        public ActionResult CalendarData()
        {
            IList<CalendarDTO> tasksList = new List<CalendarDTO>();

            tasksList.Add(new CalendarDTO
            {
                id = 1,
                title = "Google search",
                start = ToUnixTimespan(DateTime.Now),
                end = ToUnixTimespan(DateTime.Now.AddHours(4)),
                url = "www.google.com"
            });
            tasksList.Add(new CalendarDTO
            {
                id = 1,
                title = "Bing search",
                start = ToUnixTimespan(DateTime.Now.AddDays(1)),
                end = ToUnixTimespan(DateTime.Now.AddDays(1).AddHours(4)),
                url = "www.bing.com"
            });

            return Json(tasksList);
        }

        private long ToUnixTimespan(DateTime date)
        {
            TimeSpan tspan = date.ToUniversalTime().Subtract(
         new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0));

              return (long)Math.Truncate(tspan.TotalSeconds);
        }
       }
   }
```

I'm getting nothing in my view. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is a guess, but have you tried changing the order of your script includes (include jquery first, then ui, then calendar)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript include order does matter here...

You should be putting jQuery lib above the jQueryUI lib, and then the fullCalendar lib.

**EDIT**: Also, you should use the `Url.Content()` like in the first CSS tag.  This helps resolve the actual server pathing when the page loads.  You don't want to use relative pathing.

So your tags should look like...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.3.2.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>    
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/fullcalendar.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/fullcalendar.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"    />
```

**Edit 2**: 
Actually, I think I see the real reason you're not getting anything in your view.

In your layout.cshtml, you'll need to add a body tag.  Soo...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="../../Scripts/fullcalendar.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript">        </script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.3.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="../../Content/fullcalendar.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="../../Content/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"    />



</head>
<body>
    <div id="page">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
</body>
```

You need the `RenderBody()` method so the Razor engine knows where to put the view content that isn't defined in a section.  You can't have more than one `RenderBody()` method in the layout view.

Comment: Thanks David, I'll try this in a little while and mark as answer if I can get it working. Thanks!

Comment: Working now, I'll watch that in future!

Comment: I have reanderbody in, There's just no point in posting the rest of the layout page.Thanks